# Issue with the time stored with local storage and the time displayed in my inner HTML

Tags: javascript

So I am working on a Typing Test project and what my program does is have a user type up a prompt and then after the user is done, a time will be displayed on the page. Shortly after, the user will be taken to a results page with their time displayed and some other info.

As of now, I have no problem displaying the time on the first page, but when I try to display the time in the results page, I get a time that is off by 15-20 milisecs. My method of storing the user time was through using the window.localStorage method, but this made me experience a time difference in the results page. I don't know what could be causing this difference in time and was wondering if anyone had any solutions on how to save and preserve the time after timing the user.

```
//code for setting the time to the inner html.
function runTimer(){

  msecs++;

  if(msecs / 100 == 1){
     msecs = 0;
     secs++;

     if(secs / 60 == 1){
        secs = 0;
        mins++;
     }
  }

  if(msecs < 10){
     displayMsecs = "0" + msecs.toString();
  }else{
     displayMsecs = msecs;
  }

  if(secs < 10){
     displaySecs = "0" + secs.toString();
  }else{
     displaySecs = secs;
  }

  if(mins < 10){
     displayMins = "0" + mins.toString();
  }else{
      displayMins = mins;
  }
  timeSaved = displayMins +
    ":" + displaySecs + ":" + displayMsecs;
  theTimer.innerHTML = timeSaved;
}

//This is where I am saving it in localStorage

function start(){
  let textEnteredLength = testArea.value.length;
   if( textEnteredLength == 0 && timerRunning == false){
      timerRunning = true;
      interval = window.setInterval(runTimer, 10);
   }
   window.localStorage.setItem("timeSaved", timeSaved);

}
```

Comment: also add your HTML code.

Comment: You should not rely on setInterval being “exact”, especially not with such a small timeout value. This is not going to execute precisely every 10 milliseconds, but “around 10 millisecond-ish” at best. Use a Date object to check against the actual system clock.